# Customize the data in Kendo Grid pdf export

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using the built in functionality of Kendo Grid to export the grid data in pdf and excel http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export. It is working fine for me. I want to customize the data that is exported i.e. add some additional columns and remove some of the columns of grid. Is there any way to customize the export data using templates or some other feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Define a second grid with the columns that you want to export to PDF and when asked to export actually export the second. Both grids should share the datasource so filtering, orders... will be shared.
2. Intercept `pdfExport` event that is fired before the PDF is generated and hide/show the columns using `showColumn` and `hideColumn` methods.

The following code shows second approach (despite I -personally- prefer first). You will see that before clicking on export button you see `EmployeeID` but the PDF does not contain this column but includes `Country`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  kendo.pdf.defineFont({
    "DejaVu Sans"             : "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1314/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf",
    "DejaVu Sans|Bold"        : "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1314/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf",
    "DejaVu Sans|Bold|Italic" : "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1314/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
    "DejaVu Sans|Italic"      : "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1314/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf"
  });
  
  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["pdf"],
    pdf: {
      fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf",
      proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
    },
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees",
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [
      { 
        title: "Photo", 
        width: 140, 
        template :'<img src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/web/Employees/#: data.EmployeeID #.jpg" alt="#: EmployeeID #" />'
      },
      { field: "FirstName" },
      { field: "LastName" },
      { field: "Country", hidden: true },
      { field: "EmployeeID" }
    ],
    scrollable: false,
    pdfExport: function(e) {
      grid.showColumn(3);            
      grid.hideColumn(4);            
    }
  }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/pako_deflate.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.In the second option,after clicking on export button the columns listed in the grid change.I dont want that too happen.For hide/show of columns I am using ColumnMenu,that woks perfectly fine.Can you pls share the code snippet for the 1st option you have given.I am not able to follow.

Comment: My intent is to get the export data from grid and some other data source may be the same json file that is source of grid or some other json file which has some relation with the grid data.

Comment: Can you post a code example for your first suggestion? I like that much better since it doesn't change the appearance of the grid on the page. But I use the MVC extension so not very versed in using the JS grid options. I would imagine I would want to just create a new grid entirely in JS (can I do that w/o supplying a jquery selector?), copy the datasource to the new grid, and then invoker the saveAsExcel() method of the new grid?

Comment: @Onabai - can you post the code snippet for option 1. Highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with option 2, apart from not wanting to have columns magically appear during export, is the grid may not even _have_ a column for the data you wish to export.