# Hide/Show last column of kendo grid using css

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I hide the last column of my grid which has action elements while doing a PDF export.

I want to override the CSS for PDF export so as when the grid is exported the last column is hidden in the PDF.

I also have a requirement wherein I need to show the last column in the exported PDF as that grid contains data instead of action elements.Thanks

This is the CSS that I'm overriding:

```
.k-pdf-export .k-grid-toolbar,
.k-pdf-export .k-grid-pager,
.k-pdf-export .k-grid-content table tbody tr td:last-child {
    display: none;
}

.k-pdf-export .k-grid-header-wrap table thead tr th:last-child {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: even if you use CSS to hide the column the Kendo framework will still export them into your PDF.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063517/customize-the-data-in-kendo-grid-pdf-export